# hide some lines using ACE editor

Tags: javascript, tags, ace-editor

I would like to know if using ace editor is possible to hide some lines of the content of the editor.

In particular I am interested in hiding some lines like:

%Some Tag useful to find particular chunk of code in the editor

Example:

```
BEGIN My theory


%Block:Function id:tick
Myfunction() {}

END
```

I have been using The tag ( %...) to help myself to find 
Myfunction() {} , because I need to modify that particular part of code.
So, I wouldn't show that line to the user, but I would use it as tag so keeping it in the content of the editor.
I cannot use reference like the number of row because it may change.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use addFold

```
var Range=require("ace/range").Range;
editor.session.addFold("", new Range(1,0,2,0))
```

first argument to addFold is the placeholder text and the second one is the range which you want to hide

Comment: Thanks Man, just a question.
Can you explain better the meaning of placeholder text?

Comment: In older version of ace it was showing text inside of fold widget, now it still puts text there, but it gets hidden by arrow image from default css

Comment: Ok, so If I want I can change that image, can't I ?
And.. Can I change the default behaviour when the user clicks on the arrow image?

Comment: yes, add css that overrides .ace_fold rule in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/css/editor.css#L262-L286