# Hide lines in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I would like to know if it's possible to hide lines in the Ace editor?

basically, I want to put a pre-code in the editor but I don't want users to see it.

here's my code and I want to hide the first 5 lines in the editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ACE</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #editor {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor"></div>

<!-- load ace -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/theme-dracula.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ext-language_tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/keybinding-emacs.min.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    ace.require("ace/keyboard/emacs");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    self.editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
        fontSize: "11pt",
        spellCheck: true,
        wrap: false
    })
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    let precode = `var myObject = {
    field1:{
        name:'field A'
    }
}
console.log(myObject.field1.name);
`;
    editor.setValue(precode)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830070/12174914), but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is still actual.
I replaced `<entryType>...</entryType>` with empty string using this function, which is called right after editor creation:

```
function highlightEntriesTypes() {
    let editor = ace.edit("editor")
    let needle = /(^\s*<entryType>)(.*)(<\/entryType>\s*)/
    editor.$search.setOptions({
        needle: needle,
        caseSensitive: true,
        wholeWord: false,
        regExp: true,
    });
    let range = editor.$search.findAll(editor.session)
   
    
    for (const rangeKey in range) {
        editor.session.replace(range[rangeKey], "Custom content or empty string")
    }
}
```